# Which software can I use for testing RabbitMQ?

Tags: gratis, networking, rest

Currently we are using Postman as a tool for working with REST API messages, and we are looking for a similar tool for RabbitMQ. In a video, we have found the following screenshot (without the name of the program, of course):

[image]

Does this ring a bell, does anybody know a Postman replacement for RabbitMQ technology?

Thanks in advance

P.s. the name of the tool might be "Azure service bus explorer", but we have no idea if this can be used for purely local testing (without needing to access the cloud)?

P.s.2: 21 views after a week while there's a bounty of 100 points? Does this site even have members? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that using [RabbitTrace](https://github.com/rohinivsenthil/rabbitrace) has worked well for me in my use cases.  This is a [VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rohinivsenthil.rabbitrace&ref=madewithsvelte.com) that allows you to inspect your instance with the queues that I'm working with.  It can let me publish new messages and work with bindings which are my primary uses in the past with this tool.

It is relatively newer, but has been good for me so far.

If you need something different because of your use cases, maybe some more clarity of your question can help narrow down a better tool?

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I've heard of [Cogin](https://www.cogin.com/QueueExplorer/rabbitmq/), but this is not free.

Does anybody know about free software for my purpose?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community: my "answer" is not a real answer, but a way to attract more attention by putting more information. The mentioned software is not freeware, while I'm looking for a freeware solution.